# Block If without End If Error

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

I just did my first `If..Then` basic then I tried to do logical operators to compare two values in the first two cells to result in message box.  I get an `End If` Statement compile error

The actual code:

```
Sub Button3_Click()
    Dim firstnum As Long 
    Dim secondnum As Long

    firstnum = Cells(1, 1).Value
    secondnum = Cells(1, 2).Value

    If firstnum > secondnum Then
        MsgBox "The first number is greater"

    If firstnum < secondnum Then
        MsgBox "The second number is greater"
    Else
        MsgBox "The numbers are equal"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: After the edit, are you seeing what is missing..?

Comment: If you learn to properly indent your code, problems like this one don't exist because the problem slaps you in the face until you fix it.

Comment: How should it typically be indented?

Comment: @RichardGarcia See my updated answer concerning proper indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `If`, I mean this line:

> `If firstnum < secondnum Then`

should be an `ElseIf` :

```
ElseIf firstnum < secondnum Then
    ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a second `End If` here:

```
End If
End If
End Sub
```

If you indent your code properly, it would become visible.

Update: After proper formatting it becomes clear that you actually needed an `ElseIf`, see below.

---

> Your comment: How should it typically be indented?

Well, usually, after each `If` you indent the block that follows, and has to be executed if the condition following that `If` is true - when the `If` statements are nested you indent more, like:

```
If test1
    do something
    If test2
        do some more
    End If
End If
```

That way you have a good overview of the nesting, and it is harder to forget an `End If`.

In this case, after reformatting your code, it also becomes clear that you actually needed an `ElseIf` (as others already stated):

```
If test1
    do something
ElseIf test2
    do something else
Else
    last else case
End If
```

So good formatting of the code is important to avoid mistakes like that and keep a good overview. This also holds for loops etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `If <condition> Then <action>` short notation (without an `End If` after the action) you MUST put the statement in one line, either by actually having the statement in a single line:

```
If firstnum > secondnum Then MsgBox "The first number is greater"
```

or by wrapping that line using the line continuation operator (`_`):

```
If firstnum > secondnum Then _
    MsgBox "The first number is greater"
```

Otherwise you MUST use block syntax with an `End If` after the action:

```
If firstnum > secondnum Then
    MsgBox "The first number is greater"
End If
```

With that said, what you *actually* want here is an [`If..ElseIf..Else`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251599.aspx) statement, because you have three different, mutually exclusive, states (less, equal, greater):

```
If firstnum > secondnum Then
    MsgBox "The first number is greater"
ElseIf firstnum < secondnum Then
    MsgBox "The second number is greater"
Else
    MsgBox "The numbers are equal"
End If
```